# How can I extract the text of a webvtt subtitle during HLS playback in iOS?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, avplayer, webvtt

We want to extract the text of subtitle at the same time during a HLS playback. (We don't want to just display the subtitle)

Currently we can inject text data using `mediastreamsegmenter` into the MPEG-TS files and adding an observer `[self.player.currentItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata"`

But we would like to use webvtt instead of injecting the text into the MPEG-TS files.

How can I do this using webvtt?